# Check entity framework is added, modified or deleted

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm currently looking for ways to properly check whether my entitiy framework is either added, modified or deleted. Below is my coding :

```
    int state = 0;

    var added = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();
    var modified = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
    var deleted = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted).ToList();

        if (added.Count > 0)
            state = 1;
        if (modified.Count > 0)
            state = 2;
        if (deleted.Count > 0)
            state = 3;
```

Currently it is working. I just want to know if there are any other proper way to do it.

Comment: Quite honestly, I have never seen the need for such a check. If I suspect that I have pending changes, I do a SaveChanges() and move on.
Your question does make me curious as to what makes you see the need. Can you elaborate on that?


Also, I realize that your code might not be the actual one but rather a simplified version. As such, however, what will happen if one entry is changed and another is deleted? The state seems to be overwritten in your example. I guess you have a more elaborate state tracking structure in place?

Comment: @Streamcap Hi Streamcap. Actually what am I doing is I need to log the changes in my EF and put a remark on it. Example, if EF added, the remark would be "Created new (something)", if modified it would be "Update (something)". Right now, there would be only one entry that can changed at one time. Do you think it is correct? Thanks

Comment: @Farid There are indeed several ways to do this. One way (although crude) is to put a trigger in the database that writes a log line on insert/update/delete. Another is to use a logging framework, in case you need a more detailed detection of the changes. I would suggest looking into Serilog, it's free and rather powerful without demanding a ton of extra work.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the performance

- you could use `Any` instead of creating a List with all Entities.
- you don't have to determine one of the fullowing `state` values if a previous is found

Code:

```
int state = 0;

if (this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted))
{
    state = 3;
}
else if (this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified))
{
    state = 2;
}
else if (this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Added))
{
    state = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Entity framework 6, you can `override SaveChanges()`

```
public override int SaveChanges() 
{
  var addedEntites= ChangeTracker.Entries<IfYouWantSpecifyAnyType>()
                         .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Added)
                         .Select(p => p.Entity);

  var modified= ChangeTracker.Entries<IfYouWantSpecifyAnyType>()
                         .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified)
                         .Select(p => p.Entity);

  var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

  foreach (var added in addedEntites) 
  {
    added.CreatedAt = now;
    added.LastModifiedAt = now;
  }

  foreach (var modified in modified) 
  {
    modified.LastModifiedAt = now;
  }

  return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

> It will have performance impact as suggested by @Matthias Burger, also i would recommend to use a trigger or something that will stay on the database side.